# Building SDL2 on OS X 10.7: "ranlib: file: … has no symbols"

Tags: macos, makefile, sdl

When building SDL2 on lion I've run into the following when running the makefile:

```
/usr/bin/ranlib: file: build/.libs/libSDL2.a(SDL_audiodev.o) has no symbols
/usr/bin/ranlib: file: build/.libs/libSDL2.a(SDL_yuv_mmx.o) has no symbols
/usr/bin/ranlib: file: build/.libs/libSDL2.a(SDL_render_d3d.o) has no symbols
/usr/bin/ranlib: file: build/.libs/libSDL2.a(SDL_libgl2D.o) has no symbols
/usr/bin/ranlib: file: build/.libs/libSDL2.a(SDL_ndsrender.o) has no symbols
/usr/bin/ranlib: file: build/.libs/libSDL2.a(SDL_render_gles.o) has no symbols
/usr/bin/ranlib: file: build/.libs/libSDL2.a(SDL_render_gles2.o) has no symbols
/usr/bin/ranlib: file: build/.libs/libSDL2.a(SDL_shaders_gles2.o) has no symbols
/usr/bin/ranlib: file: build/.libs/libSDL2.a(SDL_getenv.o) has no symbols
/usr/bin/ranlib: file: build/.libs/libSDL2.a(SDL_malloc.o) has no symbols
/usr/bin/ranlib: file: build/.libs/libSDL2.a(SDL_qsort.o) has no symbols
/usr/bin/ranlib: file: build/.libs/libSDL2.a(SDL_stdlib.o) has no symbols
/usr/bin/ranlib: file: build/.libs/libSDL2.a(SDL_x11opengles.o) has no symbols
libtool: link: ranlib build/.libs/libSDL2.a
ranlib: file: build/.libs/libSDL2.a(SDL_audiodev.o) has no symbols
ranlib: file: build/.libs/libSDL2.a(SDL_yuv_mmx.o) has no symbols
ranlib: file: build/.libs/libSDL2.a(SDL_render_d3d.o) has no symbols
ranlib: file: build/.libs/libSDL2.a(SDL_libgl2D.o) has no symbols
ranlib: file: build/.libs/libSDL2.a(SDL_ndsrender.o) has no symbols
ranlib: file: build/.libs/libSDL2.a(SDL_render_gles.o) has no symbols
ranlib: file: build/.libs/libSDL2.a(SDL_render_gles2.o) has no symbols
ranlib: file: build/.libs/libSDL2.a(SDL_shaders_gles2.o) has no symbols
ranlib: file: build/.libs/libSDL2.a(SDL_getenv.o) has no symbols
ranlib: file: build/.libs/libSDL2.a(SDL_malloc.o) has no symbols
ranlib: file: build/.libs/libSDL2.a(SDL_qsort.o) has no symbols
ranlib: file: build/.libs/libSDL2.a(SDL_stdlib.o) has no symbols
ranlib: file: build/.libs/libSDL2.a(SDL_x11opengles.o) has no symbols
```

I don't know if this has something to do with it, but previously I had to [do this fix](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=137822) to stop it complaining about `SDL_x11sym.h:106:1`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, here's what I did:

1. Run `$ ./autogen.sh` in the terminal.
2. Open `./Xcode/SDL/SDL.xcodeproj` in Xcode.
3. Run the `Framework` target:

   [image: SDL2 framework target]
4. Open the resulting framework in the finder:

   [image: open the framework in the finder]
5. Copy `SDL2.framework` into `/Library/Frameworks/`:

   [image: copy the framework]

[image: woot]

Comment: This only works on the checkout from hg, the latest source, it didn't work on the zip file downloaded from the SDL website for 2.0